# Failed to release upgrade from 17.04 to 17.10

Tags: upgrade, 17.10, 17.04, software-sources, do-release-upgrade

Since 17.04 is no longer supported I decided to upgrade to 17.10 but faced following errors which I could not resolve:

```
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu stable Release                                                                      
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
```

Here is full log:

```
[16:44]dvinokurov@dvinokurov-WorkPC[~]$ LANG=en sudo do-release-upgrade 
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Your Ubuntu release is not supported anymore.
For upgrade information, please visit:
http://www.ubuntu.com/releaseendoflife

Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [819 B]                                                                                     
Get:2 Upgrade tool [1247 kB]                                                                                             
Fetched 1247 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                                                            
authenticate 'artful.tar.gz' against 'artful.tar.gz.gpg' 
extracting 'artful.tar.gz'

Reading cache

Checking package manager
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Ign http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                               
Hit http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                                                                 
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty InRelease                                                                     
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates InRelease                                                             
Hit https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease                                                                          
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-backports InRelease                                                           
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security InRelease                                                            
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty Release                                                                       
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]                                                                                  
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates Release                                                               
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]                                                                                  
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-backports Release                                                             
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]                                                                                  
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security Release                                                              
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]                                                                                  
Hit https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce/ubuntu zesty InRelease                                                  
Hit https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ee/ubuntu zesty InRelease                                                  
Ign https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ee/ubuntu zesty InRelease                                                  
Hit https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ee/ubuntu zesty Release                                                    
Fetched 0 B in 0s (0 B/s)                                                                                                
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done

Updating repository information

Third party sources disabled 

Some third party entries in your sources.list were disabled. You can 
re-enable them after the upgrade with the 'software-properties' tool 
or your package manager. 

To continue please press [ENTER]

Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful InRelease                                                                    
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates InRelease                                                            
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-backports InRelease                                                          
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security InRelease                                                           
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu stable InRelease                                                                    
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu stable Release                                                                      
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]                                                                                  
Fetched 0 B in 0s (0 B/s)                                                                                                
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful InRelease                                                                    
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates InRelease                                                            
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-backports InRelease                                                          
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security InRelease                                                           
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu stable InRelease                                                                    
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu stable Release                                                                      
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]                                                                                  
Fetched 0 B in 0s (0 B/s)                                                                                                
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful InRelease                                                                    
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates InRelease                                                            
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-backports InRelease                                                          
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security InRelease                                                           
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu stable InRelease                                                                    
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu stable Release                                                                      
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]                                                                                  
Fetched 0 B in 0s (0 B/s)                                                                                                

Error during update 

A problem occurred during the update. This is usually some sort of 
network problem, please check your network connection and retry. 

E:The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu stable Release' 
does not have a Release file. 


Restoring original system state

Aborting
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done
```

Could anybody help solving it?

Comment: 17.10 keeps rebooting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First we will fix your repositories :

```
sudo sed -i -re 's/([a-z]{2}\.)?archive.ubuntu.com|security.ubuntu.com/old-releases.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

This should adjust your /etc/apt/sources.list to look similar to this :

> deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-updates main
>
> deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-backports main
>
> deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security main
>
> deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty main universe restricted multiverse

Then run :

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Finally, run :

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. After editing sources.list, I still get 404 errors on running sudo do-release-upgrade.

Comment: Remember to do a restart between first and second step