# Facing issues with Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: apt, updates, 17.10, software-center

I was facing these issues in Ubuntu 17.04 :-

- Software updater missing
- Ubuntu store missing
- `apt-get update` not working

so I updated to Ubuntu 17.10 but now facing same issues and one addition is dock settings not visible. Any help will be appreciated. thanks.

Output of `apt-get update`:

[image]

Comment: Ubuntu 17.04 has reached its end of life. So, it does not get any updates, or access to the store. Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1021338/edit) your question and indicate how you upgraded to 17.10, did you use any commands, or did you use a Live USB/DVD of Ubuntu 17.10? Backing up your data and a fresh new install may be the quickest solution.

Comment: I have followed this link https://askubuntu.com/questions/1002439/unable-to-upgrade-from-ubuntu-17-04-to-17-10 to upgrade

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Instead copy & paste the text here and use [code formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help).

Comment: It looks like some of the PPAs still refer to `zesty`, which is 17.04. Could you change these to `artful` and see if that solves your problem?

Comment: I deleted conflicting PPAs from sources.list.d and now apt-get update is working, but now scrolling is not in order

Answer (score 0):

Any apt-get install will route to source list file so in order to install the necessary update from the default Ubuntu source site kindly update the source list, which will help to most resolve installation problems